# Reduce toughness and cast dmg spell - cause of death?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say on the board is a creature with toughness 6. I reduce the toughness of this creature by 3 until end of turn. After this spell resolves, I cast a burn spell which does 3 dmg to that creature. Now the creature has 0 toughness and dies but what is the cause of death? 
And how does this interact with regeneration? As fair as I understand the rules, if a creatures dies because of 0 toughness it cannot be regenerated because its not lethal damage nor a destruction event that causes death.

Comment: If you read your question carefully, you will see that you answered it just by asking it.

Comment: Since the damage from my burn spell actually causes the "lethal" damage (because its toughness is reduced by 3 until end of turn) one could assume cause of death is lethal damage and so it can be regenerated.

Comment: Yep. That is exactly it. Althought I would not say _one can assume_ it is simply fact that the burn spell does three damage to a creature with 3 toughness, so that is lethal damage. The only way they could not be regenerated is if managed to reduce the toughness through -1/-1 counter or some other way to 0. Then as a state based action, it would be moved to the grave yard.

Comment: not an duplicate, but definitely related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11367/3128

Comment: **Damage does not reduce the toughness** (though damage from sources with wither or infect can give -1/-1 counters which do reduce toughness).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you reduce a creature's toughness from 6 to 3 you just treat it as a creature of toughness 3. So dealing 3 damage to it can be regenerated. The 3 damage does not reduce the toughness to 0. It will still be a creature with toughness 3 with 3 marked damage on it that will usually die but can be saved with regeneration.