# MTG: Indestructible creature with both damage and -1/-1 counters

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

If let's say a 3/3 indestructible creature takes 2 combat damage and then 2nd main gets a -1/-1, does the creature die?

Am assuming no since its still technically a 2/2 indestructible with 2 damage on it and NOT a 3/1 indestructible with a -1/-1

Comment: nevermind, found the same question previously asked https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/can-an-indestructible-creature-die-by-a-combination-of-damage-and-x-x-effects?rq=1

Comment: Damage does not reduce toughness.

Answer (score 1):

It does not.

An indestructible creature will die from having 0 toughness.  It will **not** die from lethal damage (damage greater than or equal to its current toughness).

In your example, you have indestructible 2/2 (because of a -1/-1 counter), and it has 2 damage marked. It has taken lethal damage (as it has 2 toughness and 2 damage), but has toughness greater than 0, so it does not die.